# Video Not Playing In Chrome

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, video, html5-video

I tested the WordPress hosted video in Firefox and it works fine but not in Chrome.

Vimeo also work fine in FF but not in Chrome.

I changed the file format from MP4 to WEBM and it still doesn't work.

I've cleared file caching and cookies, enabled javascript and the latest Adobe flash.

I've also [followed these tips](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6138475?hl=en&ref_topic=3421642&vid=1-635768104343310722-2642838301).

This is how i'm printing the video in WordPress.

```
 $video_url = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'video_url', true );

 printf( '<a href="%s" class="fancybox" rel="bookmark">%s</a>', $video_url, $image );
```

Comment: This may not be an html5-video issue, but an issue with the fancyBox plug-in you appear to be using. If you want to troubleshoot it, start by adding your video url to a native html video element and see if that plays in Chrome.

Comment: I'll try that thanks